# Incorrect Result When ANTLR4 Lexer Action Invokes getText()

Tags: antlr4

It seems that the getText() in a lexer action cannot retrieve the token being matched correctly. Is it a normal behaviour? For example, part of my grammar has these rules for
parsing a C++ style identifier that support a \u sequence to embed unicode characters as part of the identifier name:

```
grammar CPPDefine;
cppCompilationUnit: (id_token|ALL_OTHER_SYMBOL)+ EOF;
id_token:IDENTIFIER //{System.out.println($text);}
;
CRLF: '\r'? '\n' -> skip; 
ALL_OTHER_SYMBOL: '\\';
IDENTIFIER: (NONDIGIT (NONDIGIT | DIGIT)*) 
  {System.out.println(getText());}
;
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment NONDIGIT: [_a-zA-Z]  | UNIVERSAL_CHARACTER_NAME ;
fragment UNIVERSAL_CHARACTER_NAME: ('\\u' HEX_QUAD  | '\\U' HEX_QUAD HEX_QUAD ) ;
fragment HEX_QUAD: [0-9A-Fa-f] [0-9A-Fa-f] [0-9A-Fa-f] [0-9A-Fa-f];
```

Tested with this 1 line input containing an identifier with incorrect unicode escape sequence:

```
dkk\uzzzz
```

The $text of the `id_token` parser rule action produces this correct result:

```
dkk
uzzzz
```

i.e. input interpreted as 2 identifiers separated by a symbol '\' (symbol '\' not printed by any parser rule).

However, the getText() of IDENTIFIER lexer rule action produces this incorrect result:

```
dkk\u
uzzzz
```

Why the lexer rule `IDENTIFIER`'s getText() is different from the parser `id_token` rule's $text. Afterall, the parser rule contains only this lexer rule?

EDIT:

Issue observed in ANTLR4.1 but not in ANTLR4.2 so it could have been fixed already.

Comment: Can you please include a complete sample to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell based on your example, but my instinct is you are using an old version of ANTLR. I am unable to reproduce this issue in ANTLR 4.2.

Comment: I updated the sample to a complete grammar. The input is 1 line as described. Problem was seen with v4.1. And the issue was not observed in v4.2. If it was not fixed intentionally, then it could be hidden accidentally.

Comment: @JavaMan I completely rewrote the lexer action index handling for 4.2.